# Want to show description of my serial number in embed google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am working on asp.net MVC and displaying data on charts using highcharts 
In my charts view i have a search functionality where i select my serial number from dropdownlist and then enter my start and end date like [image: this]

On clicking Show Chart button the data on the chart is displayed correctly
Also i am using embed google map on my site and it's displaying like 
[image: this]

Now i want is, whenever i click on show chart button the serial number's description should be shown on the map like [image: this]

I have place my search functionality in a partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MultiGraph", "Home", FormMethod.Get)){
    <div class="form-inline">
        @Html.DropDownList("search", null, "Select Serial Number", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:20%" })

        <input type='text' name="start_date" id="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input type='text' name="End_date" id="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" autocomplete="off" />
        <input id="recall" type="submit" value="Show Chart" class="btn btn-success" autocomplete="off"/>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
            <img src="~/Image/back-button.png" alt="Go Back" title="Go Back" >

        </a>
        @*<input type="button" value="Back" class="btn btn-success" onclick="@Html.ActionLink("Index","Home")"/>*@
        @*<button class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="" name="Back" value="Back"></button>*@
    </div>}
```

Rendered this partial view into my Chart view

```
<div style="font-family:'Times New Roman' ; font-size:large" align="center">

    @Html.Partial("_Search")

</div>
```

The embed google map is in my Chart layout

```
 <td style="text-align:center; width:22%; font-size:large; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:black">


                @*<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1d8zOzcF-rbJR8NqAUA9sS_o4Dy0" width="320" height="300"></iframe>*@
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1-VlXsvMWMr8EotfMcIwYKt-1SrI" width="320" height="350" style="margin-top:-383px"></iframe> </td>
```

How can i be able to perform it ? 
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: google maps api has the option to show details of  a location, i will try to find sample for you

Comment: check this sample, click the location and you will see a popover https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Comment: i don't want this i just want to view the description when i click the show chart button 

the sample is for clicking on the marker, moreover my search partial view is rendering in my charts view and the map is in my layout of charts

Comment: also i want to ask that the 'Your_API_KEY' is generated automatically ?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_backend/overview , the Google maps api key is like the permission key from  google to you to use there api's

Comment: ok, another way i can try is to hide all other marks and just show the selected mark, is this the easy way or the 1st one ?