# How to change date time format in a grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to change my date time format from `7/20/2016 10:30:00 AM` to `20 July 2016 10:30 AM`

Bellow is the image in where i want to change the format

[image]

Bellow is my code in controller where i have a events data table and in there columns i have added the event name , occurrence time and recovery time

```
DataTable events = new DataTable();
        events.Columns.Add("Event_Name", typeof(string));
        events.Columns.Add("Occurrence_Time", typeof(string));
        events.Columns.Add("Recovery_Time", typeof(string));


                while (reader_events.Read())
                {

                    events.Rows.Add(Convert.ToString(reader_events["Event_Name"]), 
                    Convert.ToString(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]).ToString(),
                    Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"]));           


                 }
```

After that i have passed these events in view data
    ViewData["events"] = events;

Bellow is my razor syntax

```
if (ViewData["events"] != null)
{
  if (ViewData.Values != null && ViewData.Values.Count() > 0)
  {
     foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in (ViewData["events"] as System.Data.DataTable).Rows)
     {
        <tr>
           <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
              @dr[0]

            </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
               @dr[1]
            </td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black; color:green;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">
              @dr[2]
            </td>
       </tr>
       }
      }
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following

```
@(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}",dr[1]))
```

in case dr[1] was string, you need to parse it  as datetime then  apply formatting like this:

```
@(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}",DateTime.Parse(dr[1])))
```

please note that the parse in order to work perfectly you need to have some culture validation

another solution, is to setup the datetime from the controller it self by using `typeof(DateTime)` instead of `typeof(string)`

for example:

1. apply the changes in the data table declaration:

> events.Columns.Add("Occurrence_Time", typeof(DateTime));

2. apply the changes in the retrieving part

> Convert.ToDateTime(reader_events["Occurrence_Time"]),

3. You can use the `string.Format` from the view side

Hope this will help you

Comment: can u confirm that the data type of dr[1] is datetime or string?

Comment: string, i a have also added my controller code please view it

Comment: i have used 'typeof(DateTime)' and parse the datetime i get an error cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: check please my last edit and confirm that  it is working for you or not, I added the changes should be applied on the controller side

Comment: added @(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}",dr[1])) insted of @(string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}",DateTime.Parse(dr[1])))

It's working now :)

Comment: can you please see my another question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524992/want-to-show-description-of-my-serial-number-in-embed-google-map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123517/discussion-between-hadi-hassan-and-faisal).

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.ParseExact,

```
 e.g.: DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Modify the code according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .ToString full date and time

```
 yourDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Convert.ToString(reader_events["Recovery_Time"])` to `reader_events["Recovery_Time"].ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt")` during adding data in datatable and check.

Comment: No overload method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments